# How can I depict a variable as a color in pandas?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider the titanic dataset, I'd like to plot a bar graph showing how sex and passenger class impact survival. I used the code below to groupby sex and passenger class to produce the attached figure. How can I eliminate the gender variable from the x-axis and express it as a color (shading the men with blue and the women with red, for example)?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
data[['Sex','Pclass','Survived']].groupby(['Sex','Pclass']).sum().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
data=data[['Sex','Pclass','Survived']].groupby(['Sex','Pclass']).sum().reset_index()
data=data.pivot(index='Pclass',columns='Sex',values='Survived')
data.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,color={'male':'b','female':'r'})
```

[image]